# How to run intern tests with sauceconnect on a remote server?

Tags: intern, saucelabs

I've been trying to run intern tests (intern 2.1) against a SauceConnect sc instance running on another machine.
I tried various configurations e.g.

```
tunnel : "SauceLabsTunnel",
tunnelOptions : {
   hostname : 'remotehost'
}
```

But that doesn't work, I'd also tried to use the proxyUrl, proxy, proxyPort options and same problem. I always receive the error `failed to remove matching tunnels`

Comment: edit: actually i've just seen a reply on irc stating that when using a remote WebDriver tunnel instance for [http://theintern.github.io/digdug](http://theintern.github.io/digdug) I should use `tunnel : 'NullTunnel'` instead. Thanks to #intern

Answer (score 0):

I'm closing this as I'd answered it, use `tunnel : 'NullTunnel'`